# Stop mongoDB using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am able to run mongodb instance without installation as below :

```
const startMongo = "mongod --dbpath /data/db";

child_process.exec(startMongo, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

The above code is working fine.

In similar way I try to stop mongo like below :

```
const stopMongo = "mongod --dbpath /data/db --shutdown";
```

But **stopMongo** command is not working. 
Also how can I check mongo already running using the same kind of code?

I am getting this error

**Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--shutdown'**

Comment: What is displayed in `stdout` and `stderr`?

Comment: You got a typo (extra quote) `"mongod --dbpath '/data/db --shutdown"` -> `"mongod --dbpath /data/db --shutdown"`

Comment: No. that's not the issue. I made typo while posting

Comment: I am getting this Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--shutdown'

Comment: Is this on Windows? You're on WIndows aren't you. No such option.

Comment: Yes I am using Windows. So what is the alternate for this?

Comment: There is no `--shutdown` or `--fork` on Windows because it does not support that type of process management. In 99.999999999% of cases you simply should be running as a "service" anyway. That's what happens in the real world deployments, so you best get used to it.

Comment: If you really must though then you can run a mongo shell with `mongo --quiet --eval 'db.getSiblingDB("admin").shutdownServer()'` as a variation on at least one of the answers given there. But you probably really just want to start the service and be done with it instead.

Comment: I am using it for desktop application where I don't want the user to install MongoDB separately. And desktop application will start and stop mongo itself.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal